# SQL select distinct or a new table?

Tags: sql, select, distinct

Let's say I have a database with a table with some columns that can be repeated often e.g. "Country" or "Event" (click,press,etc.), and I want to give the users the option to build their own query in a web page. Now I want to populate a dropdown with the available values. One option is to store the Countries and events in separate tables and build a relation between the main table and those two, then just do `select *` from the tables to populate the dropdown. The other option is to just leave them in the main table and perform a Select distinct on the fields that I want to get from the main table. Which of those two is the more robust way performance wise to achieve what I want?

Comment: There is no easy answer to your question. I guess the answer would be it depends.

Will you have caching? If so and the distinct values don't change it doesn't matter much.
What is the size of the tables? Will you be quering on index and joining on index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over time, the `select distinct` you're thinking of using to display the country/event type would become slower and slower since your main table will grow with data.

I suggest you read up on database normalization and best practices to learn more about what would work or not.

The quick answer: Use 2 tables, one to store the country, one to store the event type. Then use relationships to the main table to define it.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to have them on a separate lookup table. It's called database normalization.

For further read about the term: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Answer (score 2):

Using DISTINCT is always going to be a performance stink, where as (providing you have the correct indices on your fields) a join will be much quicker. It also means you can keep 1st normal form.

I'd advise you to test this out in your actual environment to compare the query time.

EDIT: Take a look at relational database design, if you're anything like me it opened my eyes as to how client - database performance can be optimized through the back end.